# Disable audio autoplay by blacklist in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extensions, adblock

I want disable audio autoplay on a site, as it's really annoying.

I have tried to use an Adblock rule for `xxx.com##audio`, but that did not work. It just hide the element instead of blocking it.

Only Adblock `URL FILTER` worked. But, because the audio file url in `site A` may come from `site B`.
If I use Adblock, I have to find the `site B audio file url` on `site A`, then write to blocklist.(**really inconvenient, and what if site owner change the file source from B to C? What if there are a lot of audio urls each from different site, find all by myself?** )

Is there some way to just use `css selector` to block element instead of hiding it?

Any chrome extentsion or userscript is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block all requests from site A (e.g. aaa.com) on site B (e.g. bbb.com) then you could write a filter like this:

```
||aaa.com^$domain=bbb.com
```

The components are as follows:

- `||` Any protocol and any subdomain
- `^` A slash or some other separator character
- `$` Separator between URL pattern and filter options
- `domain=` Domain filter option for specifying on which domains a filter should apply on

See also [Adblock Plus filter syntax](https://adblockplus.org/filters) in case you want to make the filter even more specific.

Comment: I know that. I have mentioned in the question that `> that's really inconvenient, and what if site owner change the file source from B to C?` , I need a way to block a element use `css selector`.Whenever you want to block a site's audio, just `xxx.com#audio`, no need to find what is the exact audio file url.

Comment: There's no way to block a request via CSS. Request blocking is done outside of the website.

What you could do is find similarities across those URLs and create a filter based on those (e.g. `.mp4^$domain=aaa.com`).